# Como verificar dados existentes em bd?

Tags: python

preciso verificar se um dado ja existe no BD antes de cadastra-lo em python, onde o bd possui a tabela VideoCapture e seus atributos sao id, nome, valor.... precisocverificar o nome antes de cadastrar no bd em python...

Comment: Será melhor você definir a coluna do banco como *unique* e tentar inserir direto, sem verificar pelo *select*. Se a coluna já existir no banco, será disparada uma exceção; basta você capturá-la e tratá-la.

Comment: Você pode usar o operador `EXISTS`, veja só: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer um SELECT com os dados que você precisa verificar se existem nessa tabela. Se o SELECT não retornar dados é porque o registro não existe caso contrário o registro existe.

Comment: sou iniciante, tem como citar um exemplo?

Comment: eu achei uma maneira

Comment: import sqlite3
import os.path


connection = sqlite3.connect('config.db')
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
     c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VideoCapture (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name text, value text)')

     sql = 'SELECT * FROM VideoCapture WHERE name = ?'
     search = 'NumCam'

     status = 0

     for row in c.execute(sql, (search,)):
          status = 1
     else:
          if status == 1:
               print('Ja cadstrado')
          else:
               c.execute("INSERT INTO VideoCapture(name, value) VALUES('NumCam', 4)")